# comparing models in R

Tags: r, model-comparison

Consider the following example:

```
x <- c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25)
y <- c(0.516,0.125,-0.0781,0,0.453,1.38,2.86,5,7.89,11.6,16.3,22,28.8)
d <- data.frame(x = x,
                y = y)

if(!require("segmented")) {
  install.packages("segmented")
  require("segmented")
}
if(!require("mgcv")) {
  install.packages("mgcv")
  require("mgcv")
}

par(mfrow = c(2,2))

# first model
g1 <- lm(y ~ x,data = d)
g2 <- segmented(g1, seg.Z = ~ x,
                psi = list(x = c(1.5)))
pdat <- data.frame(x = d$x,
                   y = broken.line(g2, link = FALSE)[,1])
pdat <- pdat[with(pdat, order(x)), ]

plot(y ~ x, data = d, pch = 21, bg = "white")
lines(y ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", col = "red")

# second model
g3 <- glm(y ~ x,data = d)
g4 <- segmented(g3, seg.Z = ~ x,
                psi = list(x = c(1.5)))
pdat <- data.frame(x = d$x,
                   y = broken.line(g4, link = FALSE)[,1])
pdat <- pdat[with(pdat, order(x)), ]
plot(y ~ x, data = d, pch = 21, bg = "white")
lines(y ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", col = "red")

# third model
g5 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data = d)
pdat <- with(d, data.frame(x = exp(seq(min(x),
                                         max(x), length = 100))))
tmp2 <- predict(g5, newdata = pdat, se.fit = TRUE)
pdat <- transform(pdat, pred = tmp2$fit, se = tmp2$se.fit)

plot(y ~ x, data = d)
lines(pred ~ x, data = pdat4, type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image]

Here, I am fitting the same data with three models.

Is there a correct way of comparing different model types?

Usually I use AIC

```
> AIC(g2,g4,g5)
   df      AIC
g2  5 45.06724
g4  5 43.06962
g5  4 32.49106
```

But I wasn't sure if this was accurate seeing as the models are different i.e. quadratic vs lm vs glm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g1` (fit with OLS) and `g3` (fit as a GLM with Gaussian family) are identical models and indeed:

```
all.equal(AIC(g1), AIC(g3))
#[1] TRUE
logLik(g1)
#'log Lik.' -36.83844 (df=3)
logLik(g3)
#'log Lik.' -36.83844 (df=3)
```

Thus, we would expect the AIC values of the corresponding segmented models also to be identical. That they aren't seems like an oversight:

```
set.seed(1)
g2 <- segmented(g1, seg.Z = ~ x,
                psi = list(x = c(1.5)),
                control=seg.control(toll=1e-100, it.max=100))
set.seed(1)
g4 <- segmented(g3, seg.Z = ~ x,
                psi = list(x = c(1.5)),
                control=seg.control(toll=1e-100, it.max=100))

all.equal(coef(g2), coef(g4))
#[1] TRUE
```

So, the coefficients are equal.

```
AIC(g2)
#[1] 45.06724
AIC(g4)
#[1] 43.06724
logLik(g2)
#'log Lik.' -17.53362 (df=5)
logLik(g4)
#'log Lik.' -16.53362 (df=5)
```

But the log-likelihood values differ exactly by 1. In `help("logLik")` we read:

> For a "glm" fit the family does not have to specify how to calculate
>   the log-likelihood, so this is based on using the family's aic()
>   function to compute the AIC. For the gaussian, Gamma and
>   inverse.gaussian families it assumed that the dispersion of the GLM is
>   estimated and has been counted as a parameter in the AIC value, and
>   for all other families it is assumed that the dispersion is known.

`segmented` doesn't seem to consider that adequately when calculating `g4$aic`.

In summary, you should be careful when using `AIC` with `segmented` models.

---

**Edit:**

I've contacted Vito Muggeo, the maintainer of the segmented package. He answered:

> Currently segmented.glm is not including the breakpoint parameter in
>   the df. Therefore there are differences equal to '2*n.of.breaks' in
>   the AIC values (and equal to "1*n.breaks" in the logLik values) [...]
>   I have corrected the code. The next version of segmented will include
>   this correction.

Answer (score 0):

How to compare models depend by the aim of your research. If you are more interested in predictive performance, a statistic like the Root Mean Squared Error of prediction RMSE (check the caret package for a quick implemenation) would probably be ok. If you are more interested in probabilistic (likelihood based) fit then AIC could be a reasonable choice